# VBA execution speed differs between Excel and Access

Tags: excel, performance, ms-access, vba

I have an Excel file with around 70-80 columns. I need to get the min and max values for each columns. I also need the min and max values on Access. I wrote the code both for Access and Excel and the speed of the macro is very different in both. Both are a little different but very similar.

Here is the Excel code :

```
Public Sub MinAndMax()
  Dim i As Long, j As Long
  Dim usedTime As Double
  usedTime = Timer

  Dim nbCol As Long, nbRow As Long
  nbCol = Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
  nbRow = Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row

  Dim min As Double, max As Double
  Dim temp As Variant

  'First column is for the table key
  'First row is for table header

  For j = 2 To nbCol
    min = Cells(2, j)
    max = Cells(2, j)

    For i = 3 To nbRow
      temp = Cells(i, j)

      If IsNumeric(temp) Then
        If temp > max Then max = temp
        If temp < max Then min = temp
      End If
    Next i
  Next j

  MsgBox "Time : " Round(Timer - duree) " seconds."
End Sub
```

This takes approximatively 5 seconds on Excel.

On Access, it's now a function returning an array, with an option indicating if you want the array with the max or min for each columns. So in order to get both min and max, I have to call it twice.

```
Private Function GetMinAndMax_Access(Optional ByVal getMin As Boolean = False) As Double()
  Dim Path As String
  Path = "C:\File.xlsx"

  Dim appExcel As Excel.Application
  Set appExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")

  appExcel.ScreenUpdating = False

  Dim wb As Workbook
  Set wb = appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path)

  Dim ws As Worksheet
  Set ws = wb.Worksheets(1)

  Dim nbCol As Long, nbRow As Long
  nbCol = ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column
  nbRow = ws.Range("A1").End(xlDown).Row    

  ReDim extremum(2 To nbCol) As Double

  Dim temp As Variant

  Dim i As Long, j As Long 'Again, data start at row 2, column 2

  For j = 2 To nbCol
    extremum(j) = ws.Cells(2, j)

    For i = 3 To nbRow
      temp = ws.Cells(i, j)

      If IsNumeric(temp) Then
        If getMin Then
          If temp < extremum(j) Then extremum(j) = temp
        Else
          If temp > extremum(j) Then extremum(j) = temp
        End If
      End If
    Next i
  Next j

  GetMinAndMax_Access = extremum

  appExcel.ScreenUpdating = True

  wb.Close SaveChanges:=False
  appExcel.Quit
End Function
```

This took precisely 29 minutes to perform on the same dataset. Note that I called the function twice, once for min values and once for max ones.

Any idea why the speeds are so different between Access and Excel, and what can be done about that ? It seems really weird to me !

Comment: [Code Review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) would be a better place to ask this question, as your code works but for some reason 1 is just very slow. Code Review is the place to ask help about working code.

Comment: I wouldn't say that code which takes 29 minutes instead of 5 seconds is working code. Code Review isn't a bad idea, but it seems that it is a good SO question as well.

Comment: 29 minutest is bad.  Step through your code in Access and see what step is taking more than a second or two.

Comment: Also check what nbCol and nbRow  are getting.  You may be needlessly looping a ridiculous amount of data that you don't need to.

Comment: I have around 36 500 rows and 75 columns. And no issues on this.

What takes the longest time is opening the excel file on access (between 10 - 15 secs ?) but that operation is only done twice, I don't need to call the sub more than that.

Every data is Excel Formula, but that's true both on the excel and the access file, so I don't see why it would change something in one of the case and not the other.

Comment: No idea why Access would be different from Excel, but I do know that you can speed up this code dramatically by eliminating the Cells method from the loop. Something like `vArray = Range(ws.Cells(1,1), ws.Cells(ws.Range("A1").End(Down).Row, ws.Range("A1").End(xlToRight).Column).Value` and then replace all ws.Cells or Cells with vArray.

Comment: Opening the file with appExcel.Workbooks.Open(Path, FALSE) may speed up the opening - it won't update any links, or turning off calculation before opening as well.

Comment: When running your VBA in Excel, all operations are taking place within the same process, but running from Access, every call to Excel must be marshalled across a process boundary before it can get to Excel.  That adds a ton of overhead, and it's the same reason why [unoptimized] .NET code written to automate Excel using VSTO can also be much slower than VBA.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Seems like a bit of a long winded way to get the minimum and maximum numeric values from the columns.  The worksheet functions MIN and MAX are pretty fast at doing it so:

In Excel:

```
Public Sub MinAndMax()

    Dim rLastCell As Range
    Dim x As Long
    Dim colMinMax As Collection

    Set rLastCell = Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=xlPrevious)

    If Not rLastCell Is Nothing Then
        Set colMinMax = New Collection
        For x = 1 To rLastCell.Column
            colMinMax.Add Array(Application.WorksheetFunction.min(Columns(x)), _
                                Application.WorksheetFunction.max(Columns(x)))
        Next x
    End If

End Sub
```

In Access (with late binding so no need to set references):

```
Sub ToUse()

    Dim MyCol As Collection
    Set MyCol = New Collection

    Set MyCol = GetMinMax("C:\Documents and Settings\crladmin.ADMINNOT\My Documents\MinMax.xlsm", "Sheet1")

End Sub

Private Function GetMinMax(sPath As String, sSheet As String) As Collection

    Dim oXL As Object
    Dim oWB As Object
    Dim oWS As Object

    Dim rLastCell As Object
    Dim x As Long
    Dim colMinMax As Collection

    Set oXL = CreateXL
    Set oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(sPath, False)
    Set oWS = oWB.Worksheets(sSheet)

    Set rLastCell = oWS.Cells.Find(What:="*", After:=oWS.Cells(1, 1), SearchDirection:=2) '2 = xlPrevious
    If Not rLastCell Is Nothing Then
        Set colMinMax = New Collection
        For x = 1 To rLastCell.Column
            colMinMax.Add Array(oXL.WorksheetFunction.min(oWS.Columns(x)), _
                                oXL.WorksheetFunction.max(oWS.Columns(x)))
        Next x
    End If

End Function

Public Function CreateXL(Optional bVisible As Boolean = True) As Object

    Dim oTmpXL As Object

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'Defer error trapping in case Excel is not running. '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    On Error Resume Next
    Set oTmpXL = GetObject(, "Excel.Application")

    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    'If an error occurs then create an instance of Excel. '
    'Reinstate error handling.                            '
    '''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''''
    If Err.Number <> 0 Then
        Err.Clear
        On Error GoTo ERROR_HANDLER
        Set oTmpXL = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
    End If

    oTmpXL.Visible = bVisible
    Set CreateXL = oTmpXL

    On Error GoTo 0
    Exit Function

ERROR_HANDLER:
    Select Case Err.Number

        Case Else
            MsgBox "Error " & Err.Number & vbCr & _
                " (" & Err.Description & ") in procedure CreateXL."
            Err.Clear
    End Select

End Function
```

Both procedures will return collections with 2D arrays containing MIN & MAX values for each column:
Item 1(0) - 4
Item 1(1) - 98
Item 2(0) - 3
Item 2(1) - 15

Comment: Hi, that code works ! It really is much more quicker to perform ! Only thing, I had to rewrite your GetMinMax function, you didn't return anything with it, so I replaced "colMinMax" by "GetMinMax" in the code. Thanks again !